# Send metrics to centralised Prometheus server without targets servers configuration

Tags: prometheus

Im trying so hard since long to setup Prometheus. Actually I need metrics from targets servers and send it to main Prometheus server. Here tricky is shouldn't configure target servers in prometheus.yml since we have thousands of servers.its really tough if we do. So any solution the targets servers should send metrics or pull metrics by Prometheus

Comment: Do you know about the various service discovery mechanisms Prometheus supports? If you don't want to follow the pull approach Prometheus is honestly not the right choice in my opinion. Take a look at something like InfluxDB or maybe VictoriaMetrics

Answer (score 1):

No, everything has to be on the prometheus.yml file.
Prometheus always pull the data, it has to know where it has to pull.

Prometheus allows to get targets from a file, that's the solution I think fits more for your problem: https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/file-sd/

Comment: Does pushprox, remote storage in proemetheus fit for the solution? any idea on these?

Comment: it fits, but again in this case prometheus has to scrap on the proxy that pushprox creates, so you have to tell it where is it.
Pushprox is a great idea in case you have a server that is not in the same network than Prometheus server, it create a proxy from one place to another, "cheating" the way Prometheus should work, but again, it has to scrap

Comment: i've seen one document pushprox(https://github.com/pambrose/prometheus-proxy). in this. here need to configure target server ip's in conf file. if you dont mind can you please refer that link. does it help me. ive tried but getting error like can not connect target server.Im sorry to trouble by asking so many questions. but literally im struggling a lot since 10days to find the appropriate sol. please reply to my questions since only this source to get help from anyone

Comment: I don't know this app, but it seems the same principle as Pushproxy. I cannot help you setting it up, but as you can read for sure ou have to write the servers to scrap on prometheus.yml

Comment: ok np, one more doubt, can we able to pass target servers ip's as file inside prometheus.yml. if we, then how?

Comment: https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/file-sd/ here it is explained how to do it. I'm updating my answer